# How to install Python libraries on a university cluster using Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

I have been working on a project that requires the installation of certain Python libraries onto a cluster. Initially, I was able to install these libraries on my local cluster by following the steps provided on this platform(link: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' when using plt.imread() in embedded Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199880/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib-when-using-plt-imread-in-emb)). However, I am now facing difficulties when attempting to install the same libraries on the university cluster.

To provide some context, I am using Ubuntu as my main operating system, and I am not utilizing any virtual machines (VMs) to run the HPCC system. Instead, I start it directly from my terminal. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on the specific command(s) I should use in my Ubuntu terminal to install the required Python modules onto the university cluster.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: "I am facing difficulties" - what difficulties? You need to be way more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Any extra libraries, such as plugins or libraries to support Python or Java embedded code, must be installed by the administrator of cluster.  An administrator has the privileged access to perform the installation, which you as a user do not have on that particular HPCC Systems cluster.  You are your own administrator for your local instance, which is why you could do that yourself.

Bottom line, reach out to the administrator of your system with a request to install specific Python libraries.